# How to print date using numeric numbers for arabic locales

Tags: node.js, icu, intl

I am using `Intl` package and try to format dates per locales.
For ar-AE example, it formats date using arabic characters but I want to print it using numeric value.

```
ops = {
    month: 'long',
    day  : 'numeric',
    year : 'numeric'
  };
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-AE', ops).format(date));
```

It prints `٢ يناير، ٢٠١٧` but I want something like `2017/01/02` or `"الاثنين، 2 يناير، 2017",`
Is this possible?

One more question - Is that possible to format using custom pattern? If I have a localized pattern, can I use the pattern and format the date?

Answer (score 3):

This is normal, because you are asking for ***ar-AE*** standard. You want the moroccan standard: ***ar-MA***:

```
var date = new Date();
ops = {month: "long", day: "numeric", year: "numeric"};

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-AE', ops).format(new Date()));
// ١٤ يناير، ٢٠١٨
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-MA', ops).format(new Date()));
// 14 يناير، 2018
```

Check at examples from [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) . They give a nice overview of date standards.

Comment: Why `console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar').format(new Date()));` outputs: `20‏/12‏/2020` It looks like it's messed up, or is it the correct format for dates in the Arabic language?

Answer (score 1):

To get numbers to be printed in **'latn'** irrespective of the locale used, then add the numbering system using `u-nu-latn` after the locale.

It will change the digits to Latin numbers **but** will keep the remaining output as per the locale. Please note the RTL direction of the output string.

```js
let ops = {
    month: 'long',
    day  : 'numeric',
    year : 'numeric'
  };
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-AE-u-nu-latn',ops).format(new Date()));
```